# Linearly Independent Dot Product Proof

Tags: linear-algebra

> Let $v_1,...,v_n$ and $w_1,...w_n$ be two sets of linearly independent
>   vectors in $\mathbb{R^n}$. Show that all their dot products are the
>   same, so $v_j \dot\ v_i = w_i \dot\ w_j$ for all $i,j = 1,...,n$ iff
>   there is an orthogonal matrix $Q$ such that $w_i = Qv_i$ for all
>   $i=1,...,n$.

My attempt:

$\langle v+w,v+w\rangle = \langle v,v\rangle+\langle v,w\rangle+\langle w,v\rangle+\langle w,w\rangle$ and since $w_i = Qv_i$ we have that $\|v\|^2 = \|w\|^2$ ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A matrix is orthogonal iff
$$
\langle Qx,Qy \rangle = \langle x,y \rangle
$$
for all $x$, $y\in \mathbb{R}^n$. Since both $\{x_1,\ldots,x_n\}$ and $\{y_n,\ldots,y_n\}$ are bases of $\mathbb{R}^n$, there exists an invertible matrix $Q$ mapping $x_j$ to $y_j$, for all $j$. Now you should be able to conclude.

Comment: Grazie tanto!!!